# What's wrong with this force download code that downloading with errors?

Tags: php, force-download

What's wrong with thisforce download code that is downloading with errors?

```
<?php

if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

$filename = $_GET['file'];

switch( $file_extension )
{     
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg": $ctype="image/jpeg";
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "mp3": $ctype="audio/mpeg3"; break;     
    case "mp3": $ctype="audio/x-mpeg-3"; break;
    case "mp3": $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;
    case "mp3": $ctype="video/x-mpeg"; break;
    case "mpa": $ctype="audio/mpeg"; break;
    case "mpa": $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

header("Content-Type: $ctype"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );  

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Please edit and add appropriate tags, like `php`. Explain what you expect, what kind of error you get.

Comment: Why are you repeating cases in your switch statement? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I cleaned up your code formatting a bit and added the [tag:php] tag. Please make sure to tag your question appropriately. That helps get it in front of people with the right skills to solve it, and also affects things like synax highlighting of code snippets. As Andrey says, please [edit] your question to include the exact error messages you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself, header Content-Type must be:

```
 header("Content-Type: ".$filename->mediaType);
```

Comment: now this service http://ekav.info/share/file/my_files of my site http://ekav.info/home is working